# File copy fails within a service when trying to access a mapped drive

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to copy a file using `File.Copy()` from my Windows Service (running as Network Service).

```
File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
```

Trouble is, when the target is on a mapped network drive, I get an error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\copiedfile.txt'

I found [someone else](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ff596ff-190a-4e7f-9d7a-fc649dda4fe7/using-filecopy-correctly) who had this problem in 2006, but that thread has an unhappy ending: the OP gave up and found a workaround.

Have any solutions been discovered in the past 7 years?

Comment: Have you tried using the full network path instead of the drive mapping ?

Comment: @abelenky - updated; not sure how much that added.

Comment: @crashmstr - I was originally using the full network path, but that was problematic because Network Service didn't have rights to the remote computer, which is on a different domain.  I created the mapping using different credentials to work around that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mappings are a per user session item, which means that while the mapping may exist on your desktop it does not exist in the service. You will need to use the UNC path instead to copy the file.

Comment: Using the UNC path is problematic, because the remote computer is on a different domain and I need to use different credentials to connect.  That's why I used the mapped drive with the required credentials.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko services should never map drives - they're a very limited resource

Comment: @Shaul the service has no understanding of the account credentials that were used to map the drive. You may be able to use impersonation to get access to saved credentials for the resource, or you could consider running the service under a known user account

Comment: OK, thanks, you've at least explained why my code doesn't work, so that's answer credit to you.  I may ask another question later about how to resolve this... maybe I'll use ftp...

Answer (score 2):

> A service should not directly access local or network resources
>   through mapped drive letters. Additionally, a service should not use
>   the WNetXXXXXXX APIs to add, remove, or query any mapped drive
>   letters. Although the WNetXXXXXXX APIs may return successfully, the
>   results will be incorrect. A service (or any process that is running
>   in a different security context) that must access a remote resource
>   should use the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name to access the
>   resource.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9a702da-724b-4acc-a1bb-ac4d225838c8/copy-file-to-a-mapped-drive

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180362/en-us